execute ros2 run command on self wrote packages
im having some hard time trying to solve this bug:

system: ubuntu 24.04 LTS
ROS2 distro: Jazzy

I wrote a simple subscribe to teleop_twist_keyboard node to a topic then send Serial signal to my Arduino. But when i use "colcon build", there is a warning when they all done:
Finished <<< serial_motor_demo_msgs [1.36s]                     
Starting >>> py_pubsub
--- stderr: py_pubsub                   
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  easy_install.initialize_options(self)
---
Finished <<< py_pubsub [1.74s]

Summary: 2 packages finished [3.20s]
  1 package had stderr output: py_pubsub 

so its successfuly build with a warning. But when i try to run it, its got error. I was thinking of the python that made the error but i got nothing.

ros2 run py_pubsub drive_convert

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 322, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taopeter/ros2_ws/install/py_pubsub/lib/py_pubsub/drive_convert", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('py-pubsub', 'console_scripts', 'drive_convert')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/taopeter/ros2_ws/build/py_pubsub/py_pubsub/publisher_member_function.py", line 46, in main
    node = teleop_serial()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/taopeter/ros2_ws/build/py_pubsub/py_pubsub/publisher_member_function.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout = 1)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 325, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1 

I did try to test it on multiple machine but its keep getting these errors.
Heres my code:

Im kinda new to this so i dont realy know what info I need to give to get further helps so please tell me and I will answer with more info too solve this problem

This is the important bit in your error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'  

It is telling you that python can't find/access that serial bus. First you should try running ls /dev in a console to ensure that there is in fact a port with that name. If there is, you may need to edit the user rules for your machine to give python permission to read/write to that port. If you find the port with ls, try running sudo chmod 0666 /dev/ttyUSB0. This is a temporary fix, but if it works then your issue is with the user rules, and you can look into declaring them properly.

yeah thanks for your suggestion. But it just solves the USB problem tho, and i still can not run the node.
anyways really appreciate your help!

@PeterTheSeaweed Is it giving you a different error now that the USB issue is fixed?

it works now but still outputting weird warnings so I kept looking for a solution

You should update your question with the errors so we can understand the problem.
